# Merged two dataframe depending on the dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe that have not the same lenght:

df1:

```
2000-01-31,9
2000-02-28,8
2000-03-31,7
2000-04-30,6
2000-05-31,5
2000-06-30,4
2000-07-31,3
2000-08-31,2
2000-09-30,1
2000-10-31,0
2000-11-30,11
2000-12-31,12
```

and df2 which is shorter:

```
2000-05-31,9
2000-06-30,2
2000-07-31,6
2000-08-31,4
2000-09-30,3
2000-10-31,0
2000-11-30,1
```

How could I merge the corresponding dates of df1 into df2?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2])` will stack the first dataframe on top of the second.  You may then wish to sort on your date column via `sort_values('your_date_column_name')`.  If you want the data side-by-side, could you please include your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert date into time stamp then merge on that column , if you want include all dates you can use 'outer' join

dataframe

df1

```
    0   1
0   2000-01-31  9
1   2000-02-28  8
2   2000-03-31  7
3   2000-04-30  6
4   2000-05-31  5
5   2000-06-30  4
6   2000-07-31  3
7   2000-08-31  2
8   2000-09-30  1
9   2000-10-31  0
10  2000-11-30  11
11  2000-12-31  12
```

df2

```
    0   1
0   2000-05-31  9
1   2000-06-30  2
2   2000-07-31  6
3   2000-08-31  4
4   2000-09-30  3
5   2000-10-31  0
6   2000-11-30  1


df1.merge(df,on=[0],how='inner')
```

out:

```
           0    1_x 1_y
0   2000-05-31  9   5
1   2000-06-30  2   4
2   2000-07-31  6   3
3   2000-08-31  4   2
4   2000-09-30  3   1
5   2000-10-31  0   0
6   2000-11-30  1   11
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need all the rows from `df1` and `df2` including dates and values. You can concat the dfs

```
import pandas as pd
df3=pd.concat([df1,df2])
print(df3)
date    value
1/31/2000   9
2/28/2000   8
3/31/2000   7
4/30/2000   6
5/31/2000   5
6/30/2000   4
7/31/2000   3
8/31/2000   2
9/30/2000   1
10/31/2000  0
11/30/2000  11
12/31/2000  12
5/31/2000   9
6/30/2000   2
7/31/2000   6
8/31/2000   4
9/30/2000   3
10/31/2000  0
```